# query hive in bigquery

Tags: sql, hive, google-bigquery

I want to compute a new column c1, which is the collect_set of column **typpl**, then concat the result of collect_set, finally delete escape from result. In Hive the query is:

```
select distinct numcat,numpl,numcr, natcat, cdvign, translate(concat_ws('!',collect_list(cast(typpl as string)) over(partition by numcat,numpl,numcr, natcat, cdvign) ), ' ','') c1 from db.table
```

How can I convert this query ( concat_ws and collect_list ) in Bigquery standard SQL?

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should be doing.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff for your comment I updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to convert this query ( concat_ws and collect_list ) in Bigquery standard SQL.

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

The direct "translation" would look like below

```
select distinct 
  numcat,
  numpl,
  numcr, 
  natcat, 
  cdvign, 
  translate(
    array_to_string(
      array_agg(typpl) over(partition by numcat,numpl,numcr, natcat, cdvign), '!'
    ), ' ', ''
  ) c1
from `db.table`
```

meantime, you can simplify "a little" as in below

```
select distinct 
  numcat,
  numpl,
  numcr, 
  natcat, 
  cdvign, 
  translate(
    string_agg(typpl, '!') over(partition by numcat,numpl,numcr, natcat, cdvign), 
    ' ', ''
  ) c1
from `db.table`
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a simple aggregation:

```
select numcat, numpl, numcr, natcat, cdvign, 
       array_agg(cast(typpl as string)) as c1
from db.table
group by numcat, numpl,numcr, natcat, cdvign
```